# how can i print the upper triangle of a matrix

Tags: linux, shell, loops, awk, sed

using awk command I tried to print the upper triangle of a matrix

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (i>=NR) printf  $i FS "\n"}' matrix
```

but the output is shown as a single row

Answer (score 2):

Consider this sample matrix:

```
$ cat matrix
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

To print the upper-right triangle:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",(i>=NR)?$i:" ",FS; print""}' matrix
1 2 3 
  5 6 
    9
```

Or:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%2s",(i>=NR)?$i:" "; print""}' matrix
 1 2 3
   5 6
     9
```

To print the upper-left triangle:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF+1-NR;i++) printf "%s%s",$i,FS; print""}' matrix
1 2 3 
4 5 
7
```

Or:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF+1-NR;i++) printf "%2s",$i; print""}' matrix
 1 2 3
 4 5
 7
```

Comment: Why not use a ternary for the second `%s` too: `{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",(i<NR?FS:$i),(i<NF?FS:RS)}` - I also moved the parentheses as I think I remember it being more widely compatible this way.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;n;H;G;s/\n//;:b;s/^\S+\s*(.*)\n.*/\1/;tb;$!ba' file
```

Use the hold space as a counter for those lines that have been processed and for each current line remove those many fields from the front of the current line.

N.B. The counter is set following the printing of the current line otherwise the first line would be minus the first field.

On reflection an alternative/more elegant solution is:

```
sed -r '1!G;h;:a;s/^\S+\s*(.*)\n.*/\1/;ta' file
```

And to print the upper-left triangle:

```
sed -r '1!G;h;:a;s/^([^\n]*)\S+[^\n]*(.*)\n.*/\1\2/;ta' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{for (i=NR;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",$i,(i<NF?FS:RS)}' file
1 2 3
5 6
9
```